# Using class methods to return instances and simply defining __init__(self, **kwargs):

Tags: python, attr, python-dataclasses, python-attrs

One pattern I recently started using is writing class methods to return instances. In particular, I've been using it for dataclasses (with or without the @dataclass decorator). But it has also led me to defining vague __init__ methods as follows:

```py
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs:
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

As a more fleshed out example, let's say I'm writing a metadata class that holds the details of a standardized test question. I expect all instances of the class to have the same attributes, so I use __slots__, and I have functions defined in another module to read various parts of the question from an html file.

```py
class Metadata:
    __slots__ = question_id, testid, itemnum, subject, system, topic, images, tables, links

    @classmethod
    def from_html(cls, html: BeautifulSoup):
        # next two lines will create the dict metadata with keys for 
        # everything in __slots__
        metadata = MyModule.parse_details(html)
        metadata['images'] = MyModule.process_images(html)
        metadata['tables'] = MyModule.read_tables(html)
        metadata['links'] = MyModule.pull_links(html)
        return cls(**metadata)
        
    @classmethod
    def from_file(filepath: str):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            metadata = json.load(f)
        return cls(**metadata)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs:
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

So to me this seems like the best way to accomplish the task, which is create a dataclass to hold metadata which can be initialized from multiple different sources (files, dicts, other dataclasses I've defined, etc). The downside is that __init__ is very opaque. Also it feels weird to use **kwargs when the __init__ has to take the same keyword arguments every time for the class to work as I intend (that's partly why I used __slots__ too: to make the definition of the dataclass more clear).

Also the [documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html) of the `attrs` package for Python says this:

> For similar reasons, we strongly discourage from patterns like:
>
> ```py
> pt = Point(**row.attributes)
> ```
>
> which couples your classes to the database data model. Try to design your classes in a way that is clean and convenient to use – not based on your database format. The database format can change anytime and you’re stuck with a bad class design that is hard to change. Embrace functions and classmethods as a filter between reality and what’s best for you to work with.

That's near the top of the page of the link I included, and I really don't understand what it's trying to say, hence my question.

So would you implement my code any differently, and what is the attrs documentation trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

and you initialize your class doing

```py
class Post:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

import json

with open(filepath, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    post = Post(**data)
```

The following code

```py
if not post.completed:
   # do something and exit
else:
   print(post.userId)
```

will work as expected. However, suppose you need to rename e the `userId` column to `user_id` (the "The database format can change anytime" part of the documentation). Now you need to rename ALL the occurences of `post.userId` to `post.user_id` in all of your code. It's fine if your codebase consists of only one Python file, but what if it contains a lot of files and dependencies?

Now suppose you initialize your class doing

```py
class Post:
    def __init__(self, postId, id, title, completed):
        self.postId = postId
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.completed = completed

import json

with open(filepath, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    post = Post(
        postId=data['postId'],
        id=data['id'],
        title=data['title'],
        completed=data['completed'],
    )
```

Now if `postId` is renamed to `post_id`, you only need to change ONE place in your whole codebase: when you read from the JSON file.

Other situations include

- your database designer adding a column named `aVeryLongFieldNameThatYouDoesNotWantYoInsertIntoYourPythonCode`
- some linter complaining the Python attributes should be `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`
- you wanting to typecheck your code using `mypy`, which does not work very well with `setattr`